# Android:AudioTrack support?

Tags: android

I like to know on which version of SDK does support 'AudioTrack' class? Does 'AudioTrack' can be used from 1.5 SDK, 1.6 SDK and 2.0 SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the AudioTrack class support was added in SDK3/Platform 1.5 so anything newer than that should be fine.

You can always create a test app with minSDKver set to 3 and platform set to 1.5 and see if you are getting errors.

I am sure you have looked at the Documentation , but here it is.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

Comment: It clearly DOES state which versions support that class.  In the top right corner of the page it says "Since API Level 3", which is OS version 1.5.